# Create and Modify Map in MongoDB in Erlang

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, erlang

I want to use mongodb as a map in Erlang. I cannot find an example of this. This is what I have so far:

```
application:start(mongodb).
Host = {localhost, 27017}.
{ok, Conn} = mongo:connect(Host).

mongo:do(safe, master, Conn, test, fun() ->
    mongo:delete(foo, {}),                 
    mongo:insert(foo, {x,1}),
    mongo:insert(foo, {a,12}),
    Pid = mongo:find(foo, {a}),    
    Result = mongo_cursor:rest(Pid),                
    mongo_cursor:close(Pid),
    Result end).
```

Result:

```
{ok,[{'_id',{<<80,138,211,178,41,152,132,104,251,0,0,35>>},
            x,1},
     {'_id',{<<80,138,211,178,41,152,132,104,251,0,0,36>>},
            a,12}]}
```

Why does it create two maps?

Comment: Someone found this question helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing two inserts into MongoDB without specifying any `_id` value, so end up with two documents and an autogenerated unique ObjectId. If you are trying to use a collection similar to a `map` or `dict`, you should be providing an `_id` value as the key and use [`repsert` (aka upsert)](http://api.mongodb.org/erlang/mongodb/mongo.html#repsert-3) to update the document if it exists already (or insert if it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

mongo is not map is list of maps there no way to modify map themselves